# Convert tap point to focus interest point in GPUImageView

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, gpuimage

I'm using GPUImage framework for live photo editing.

I have structure, like this:
- GPUImageStillCamera
-- GPUImageCropFilter
--- Other visual filters
---- GPUImageView

I want to convert tap point from GPUImageView to point in GPUImageStillCamera coordinates, because It's needed to set focus point.

My crop filter initialization:

```
cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0.06f, 0.0f, 0.9, 1.0f)];
```

GPUImageView fill mode is default.

Have you any ideas or sample?

Answer (score 1):

// get POI

```
CGPoint viewCoordinates=[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
CGSize frameSize=self.view.frame.size;
CGPoint  pointOfInterest = CGPointMake(viewCoordinates.y / frameSize.height, 1.f - (viewCoordinates.x / frameSize.width));
```

may b helpful

Comment: What a pity, that GPUImageView still does not expose AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, which has a method for this https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturevideopreviewlayer/1623497-capturedevicepointofinterest.